# How to query for values that share another value in common

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

Greenplum 4.2.2.4 (like PostgreSQL 8.2) on server.

I have data like:

```
id    | user
------+------
12345 | bob
12345 | jane
12345 | mary
44455 | user1
44455 | user2
44455 | user3
67890 | bob
53756 | bob
53756 | bob
53756 | bob
25246 | jane
54383 | jane
54383 | jane
54383 | jane
```

I only want to return rows where the "id" is shared by multiple unique "user" values. However, I'm also querying based on a list of "user" values that I am interested in. For example:

> WHERE user IN ('mary','bob','user2')

I want the query to return:

```
id    | user
------+------
12345 | bob
12345 | jane
12345 | mary
44455 | user1
44455 | user2
44455 | user3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It remains unclear whether you want to collapse duplicates on `(id, user)` in the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select id, user
from (select t.*, min(user) over (partition by id) as minuser,
             max(user) over (partition by id) as maxuser
      from table t
     ) t
where minuser <> maxuser;
```

EDTI:  Without window functions (which I thought were around since Postgres 8.1 but I trust Erwin on this matter), you can do the same thing with a `join` and `group by`:

```
select t.id, t.user
from table t join
     (select user, min(user) as minuser, max(user) as maxuser
      from table t
      group by user
      having min(user) <> max(user)
     ) tu
     on t.user = tu.user;
```

Comment: Answer doesn't work for Postgres 8.2, which does not know window functions (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

In t1, the repeated rows that are not unique (like <53756, bob>) are converted to one record.

Then, in the outer parentheses, those id's shared with only one user are filtered (like <25246, Jane> or <53756, bob> that is now converted to one record).

The records with these id's are the answer then:

```
select *
    from OriginalTable
    where id in 
        (
        select id 
            from ( 
                select distinct id, user
                    from OriginalTable
                ) as t1
            group by id
            having count(*) > 1
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query out. I tested in a postgresql table with 3.5 million rows and it took roughly 1.7 seconds.

```
select id,
       uname 
from   (
    select 
           id,
           uname,
           count(*) over (partition by id,uname) as count_of_unique_id_share,
           count(*) over (partition by id) as count_of_id_share 
    from 
           (select * from (select distinct id,uname from <TABLE>) z 
        where  id in (select id from <TABLE> where uname in ('mary','bob','user2')))y ) x 
where 
        count_of_unique_id_share = 1 and count_of_id_share > 1
```

Comment: Answer doesn't work for Postgres 8.2, which does not know window functions (yet).

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bc7d7/1)

```
select id, "user"
from
    (
        select id
        from t
        group by id
        having
            count(distinct "user") > 1
            and
            array['mary','bob','user2']::varchar(5)[] && array_agg("user")
    ) s
    inner join
    t using (id)
order by id, user
```

Comment: Fails for `(44455, 'user1'), (44455, 'user2')`, since `user1` is excluded in subquery `s`.

Comment: @Erwin _Fails_ is too strong a word here since it is not clear if that is indeed the OP's intent.

Comment: I am deriving my interpretation from the demo output, so the proper wording might be "produces a different result than what's displayed".

Answer (score 0):

Postgres 8.2 does not *have* window functions (introduced with version 8.4).
Since you are looking for rows where

> the "id" is shared by multiple unique "user" values.

```sql
SELECT t2.id, t2.user
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 USING (id)    -- retrieve all rows with same id
WHERE  t1.user IN ('mary','bob','user2')
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  id = t1.id
   AND    user <> t1.user   -- at least one other user with same id
   )
ORDER  BY t2.id, t2.user;
```

Names are symbolic. One wouldn't use the [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) <strike>`user`</strike> as identifier.

This variant *may* be faster:

```sql
SELECT id, user
FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM   tbl t1
    WHERE  user IN ('mary','bob','user2')
    AND    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM   tbl
        WHERE  id = t1.id
        AND    user <> t1.user
        )
    ) sub
JOIN   tbl USING (id)
ORDER  BY id, user;
```

Either query returns *all* rows as per your request - *including complete duplicates*. If you only want distinct rows:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id, user ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE users( id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , username varchar
        );

INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES
  (12345 , 'bob' )
, (12345 , 'jane' )
, (12345 , 'mary' )
, (44455 , 'user1' )
, (44455 , 'user2' )
, (44455 , 'user3' )
, (67890 , 'bob' )
, (53756 , 'bob' )
, (53756 , 'bob' )
, (53756 , 'bob' )
, (25246 , 'jane' )
, (54383 , 'jane' )
, (54383 , 'jane' )
, (54383 , 'jane' )
        ;

SELECT *
FROM users u1
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM users u2
        -- id must at least have one of these three usernames
        WHERE u2.username IN ('mary','bob','user2')
        AND u2.id = u1.id
        AND EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM users u3
                WHERE u3.id = u2.id
                -- and there must exist a different username for this id
                AND u3.username <> u2.username
                )
        );
```

---

result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 14
  id   | username 
-------+----------
 12345 | bob
 12345 | jane
 12345 | mary
 44455 | user1
 44455 | user2
 44455 | user3
(6 rows)
```

Comment: My first draft only returned the core row. Q asks for all rows sharing the same id though, which is reflected in my update.

Comment: I had not seen yours yet when I started, and did not want to delete mine. The problem is yet another corner case of relational division. Oops, now I see, I forgot the constant `in(...)`. BRB...